# Function which takes on every value in $[0,1]$ an infinite number of times.

Tags: examples-counterexamples

> Give an example of a continuous real-valued function $f$ form $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ which takes on every value in $[0,1]$ an infinite number of times.

---

My example goes like this: Take $f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} g(x)$ where. $$g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
n x, \frac{k}{n} \leq x \leq \frac{k+1}{n} ; k \text { is even } \\
-n x, \frac{k}{n} \leq x \leq \frac{k+1}{n} ; k \text { is odd }
\end{array}\right.$$ Does this work? I'm unable to verify.

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions.

Comment: Can downvoter please explain. Thank you.

Comment: @5xum that comment was made before I saw your comment. Also thank you, I did indeed tried Latex before, but for some reason it was showing error, you may check the latex in edit history. That's why I attached pic instead.

Comment: Here's the latex that it's showing error to $$g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
n x, \frac{k}{n} \leq x \leq \frac{k+1}{n} ; k \text { is even } \\
-n x, \frac{k}{n} \leq x \leq \frac{k+1}{n} ; k \text { is odd }
\end{array}\right$$

Comment: You should use `begin{cases} [insert thing] \end{cases}` instead of trying to use left and right with no delimiter behind right.

Comment: Try using the `cases` environment instead of array. If you simply followed the link I provided you would easily find this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5025#5025

Comment: Are you sure the question is for a function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$, not from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$?

Comment: @5xum yes that's how it was given. It's from 1959 Putnam B3. For $(0,1)$, $\sin (1/x)$ would work fine

Comment: @zaemon_23 Then I think I have a pretty solid proof that $f$ cannot exist. I could be wrong but I can't really see where (which... you know... is always the case until one gets proven wrong, of course :D)

Comment: This is quite a hard question. There are examples [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/345806) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/18666).

Comment: Like I said, I could be wrong :D

Comment: Is the question really "give an example" (in the sense of explicitly writing down such a function) or "prove such a function exists"?